# Creating if statment in Django Crispy Forms, conditional form layout

Tags: django, if-statement, conditional-statements, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django Crispy Forms. I want to write an if-else statement. When the value of field name is "Daisy", then the Age field should appear, otherwise there should not be a field 'age".

My code:

````
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      
     self.helper.layout = Layout(

         HTML(form_opening.format('Cats')),
         'name',
         'age',
          HTML(form_closing),
         
     ),
    ```
````

Comment: What if there is no value for the `name` field? (at the time of creation)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu if there is no value for the `name` field i think that age field should  be visible.

Comment: Im not sure you'd do that in the form class. I'd probably just wrap it in an `if` statement in the template, or is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Alternatively, not sure if this would work, but `"age" if name = "Daisy" else None` ?? Worth a try maybe ...

Comment: @urbanespaceman 
Can you say how would you do it exactly? How would you wrap it in an if statment in the template?

Comment: You'd have to move some of the  form design to the template, rather than relying on the helper layout and just saying `{% crispy form %}`. Then you could just wrap that field in an `{% if name == "Daisy" %}...{% endif %}` block.

Comment: Another thought ... in `__init__` could you just `del self.fields["age"]` if the name is daisy? Not sure if that would work or not ... never tried it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this one on one of my own forms, and it works nicely :)

In the `__init__` function:

```
if getattr(self.instance, "name", None) == "Daisy":
    del self.fields["age"]
```